# Incompatibility with Galaxy Note

Tags: android

I have an Android app which is written to minimum SDK version 7.

In my manifest i use the following requirements

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

This app runs fine on my HTC Sensation XE running Android 2.3.4, and on my Galaxy Tab 10.1 running android 3. When I wanted to install my app on a Galaxy Note, I couldn't find my app in the Market. I tried following a link to the app, and it said that the app was not compatible with the Galaxy Note.

Is there any reason why this is so? Can the Galaxy Note only run SDK version 9 or higher? Or do I have some sort of limiting requirement in my manifest?

Comment: Did you ever solved this? I have the same problem with another device (Chinese made Oppo N1)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you still need this, but I think you also need to have:

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I think Galaxy Note belongs to xlarge category.